# Linking html file to a css file which is in a subdirectory doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a folder with my loginform.html and a CSS subdirectory with a simple CSS file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<header>
<title>Login Forms</title>

<link href="CSS/LoginForm_CSS_1.css" rel="stylesheet">

</header>
<body>   
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I cannot link them, and I cannot understand why, I tried:

`<link href="CSS/LoginForm_CSS_1.css" rel="stylesheet">`

and

`<link href="/CSS/LoginForm_CSS_1.css" rel="stylesheet">`

and

`<link href="../CSS/LoginForm_CSS_1.css" rel="stylesheet">`

but nothing works, when I put the LoginForm_CSS_1.css file in the same directory as the html file and use `<link href="LoginForm_CSS_1.css" rel="stylesheet">` everything are ok. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look over directory structure...Where HTML file is placed beside the CSS file? Then you will got it.

Comment: BTW you probably wanted to write `"./CSS/…"` instead of the double dot

Comment: `<link href="CSS/LoginForm_CSS_1.css" rel="stylesheet">` should work, but make sure you stick with lower case without underscores

Comment: @Mr.Alien yeah, that's the correct, it was mine misspelling mistake, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<link href="CSS/LoginForm_CSS_1.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

head tag is for root, header tag should be in the body!